# Group by one column but sum two others and count a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My df

```
df_RFQ_by_Salesperson = df[
                          (df['state'].str.contains('Done'))
                          ][['sales_person_name2',
                             'rfq_qty',
                             'rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv',
                             'state'
                            ]].copy()

display(df_RFQ_by_Salesperson.head(3))

    sales_person_name2  rfq_qty     rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv   state
14  AY                 200000.0     2.568713e+05        Done
22  AY                 1000000.0    1.284357e+06        Done
28  YJJ               25000000.0    4.420085e+07        Done
```

I would like to `groupby` on `df_RFQ_by_Salesperson`, `sum` on `rfq_qty`, `sum` on `rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv` but `count` on `state` then add a percentage column based on `rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv`. I have figured out the sum and percentage columns but I'm not sure how to loop in the count of state?

```
df_RFQ_by_Salesperson = df_RFQ_by_Salesperson.rename(columns={'state':'Done Trades'}, level=0) # rename the column header in the groupby
df_RFQ_by_Salesperson = df_RFQ_by_Salesperson.groupby(['sales_person_name2'])['rfq_qty','rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].sum() 
Total_Done_Volume = df_RFQ_by_Salesperson['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].sum()
df_RFQ_by_Salesperson['Percentage'] = df_RFQ_by_Salesperson['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].div(Total_Done_Volume)

display(df_RFQ_by_Salesperson.sort_values('Percentage',ascending=False))

sales_person_name2  rfq_qty     rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv   Percentage  Count of State      
MP                  214400000.0 3.045802e+08        0.258089        ?
AC                  228800000.0 2.648099e+08        0.224390        ?
YJJ                 202500000.0 2.490527e+08        0.211038        ?
RW                  129000000.0 1.693008e+08        0.143459        ?
AY                  118366000.0 1.189635e+08        0.100805        ?
RL                  78617000.0  7.342725e+07        0.062219        ?
```

Is it possible to do a count in conjunction with a sum in the one groupby?

Comment: Is the only possible value in the `state` column `Done`? If so, try something like `df_RFQ_by_Salesperson.groupby('sales_person_name2')['state'].count()`

Comment: State can have Done or Tied Done. I'd like to incorporate the summ and couts into the one statement, if possible

Comment: @PeterLucas, i'm not sure if a `count` / `size` on the `state` column gives you what you want, but its in my answer. I think what you need is a count of different states per sales person, which requires a group by on sales person & state. please clarify, and I can update the answer

Comment: Answer below is on the money! Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can aggregate multiple columns with different functions by specifying a map from from column name to function:

```
out = df.groupby('sales_person_name2').agg(
 {'rfq_qty': 'sum', 'rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv': 'sum', 'state': 'size'}
)
```

and then calculate the percentage separately and assign to a percentage column

```
out['percentage'] = out.rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv / out.rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv.sum()
```